# Cat behaving like dog, is it of any particular breed?

Tags: cats

I had a cat when I was a younger early teens. He didn't live particularly long, died of a heart attack around 5 years old. A previous girl friend convinced me to get a cat and it was just a horrible experience, was nothing like how I remember my cat being, it was skittish, hated to be around people, would just hide under crap whenever anyone came over. I can't seem to remember the specific breed my old cat was but he was half something.

To describe his personality is kind of hard. If I was to say what he was most like I'd say a dog ... whenever I called his name he would come running immediately no matter where we were (he was once 80 ft up a tree in our yard, so I called him cause everyone was worried that probably he was stuck and he just turned and leapt out of the tree sprung snapped on the ground and ran over to me immediately like nothing had happened). Whenever you were around he'd follow you around like a dog, whenever you were doing something say under a car working on it he was right there beside you staring at whatever you were doing. Now my grandfather hated cats but when he got me from my mother he got the cat too and even though it met him when he was nearly 2 years old the cat was the same with him. Whether he was working on car shovel, snowing off a roof, going fishing at the creek beside our house in the pouring rain, he could find the cat under the closest tree standing at attention watching. Our neighbour was redoing his floor and left the front door open halfway through. While installing the floor he decided to take a break and looked over at his chair to find my cat sitting there at attention intently watching him working.

I would often go fishing from our place and he would frequently hop into the boat and come with me, he wasn't afraid of anything, even my grandfather doing bodywork (smashing metal with big hammers and welding). The cat wouldn't be far away watching him and when the loud noise stopped he'd be inches away from whatever was being fixed.

The moment anyone walked up to him he would purr as loud as a two stroke motor roll onto his back and wait to be petted. When I say anyone I mean literally any random stranger, he'd just roll over onto his back and purr away. He loved to be picked up and held for some reason. He liked to be held like a baby on his back which was quite odd but would happily purr away.

Though he could meow I think I only heard him do it twice in his life once when he got a fishhook in his tail and we had to get it out and the first day he was away from his mother when we got him he meowed once that night. He was also quite large not fat but just well big like really big for a cat some of it was his really long fur but he was also well built. And whenever I would pet him, he liked to need but mostly just with his claws in but he'd put much effort with paw really pushing hard down with his front legs over and over again.

Is this behaviour something that's normal for a particular breed of cats or was he just a miracle cat? I am asking because I am considering getting a cat but would like one that likes to be around people and being petted if possible curious and likes to know what I'm doing. I realize I am asking for a dog that happens to be a cat but ya never know maybe something like that exists.

EDIT: to make it abundantly clear i was asking what kind of cat he could of been based on the behaviour above. though there are actually a couple options based on above the fulfill many of what i listed but only one to my knowledge fulfilling all of them additionally given his appearance there was only one choice from the possible candidates.

Comment: Clearly the best answer and correct answer is Ragdoll cat as researched by OP himself. So I think this is a legit question and should be reopened.

Answer (score 3):

You will never get the perfect old cat back. It was one of a kind. But this does not mean your next cat will not be as good or even better than the previous cat.

And there is no reason for you to get a kitten only. It is possible to get an adult cat from a shelter, and it is often easier to see the personality in an adult cat.

Your fear of the cat dying is a natural one, but it is a lot easier for a vet to examine an adult cat to listen for heart problems.

Take your time in finding the right cat for you. And cats can have totally different personality even if they come from the same litter. You will find the right cat but do not rush it.

Answer (score 2):

So I did some googling and eventually found out that he was probably half "ragdoll", one of the pictures on the internet could be literally of him.

Apparently this particular breed of cats tends to act in that way. The going limp on being picked up, the over friendliness to strangers and other animals. Even the puppy-like curiosity in everything its owner is doing. They also don't have a tendency to vocalise in terms of meowing often.

Surprised no one knew of this breed of cats.

Comment: http://www.catster.com/cats-101/about-the-ragdoll-cat